# How to remove the specified option from right click meun in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to remove the image property option from the right click menu in tinymce. I'm using tinymce 3.x version please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do something like:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(editor_oninit);
    }
...
});

function editor_oninit(ed) {
    // Add hook for onContextMenu so that Insert Image can be removed
    ed.plugins.contextmenu.onContextMenu.add(editor_remove_image);
}
```

And the function

```
function editor_remove_image(sender, menu) {
    // create a new object
    var otherItems = {};
    for (var itemName in menu.items) {
        var item = menu.items[itemName];
        if (/^mce_/.test(itemName)) {
            if (item.settings) {
                if (item.settings.cmd == "mceImage" || item.settings.cmd == "mceAdvImage") {
                    // skip these items
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        // add all other items to this new object, so it is effectively a clone
        // of menu.items but without the offending entries
        otherItems[itemName] = item;
    }
    // replace menu.items with our new object
    menu.items = otherItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this **TinyMCE** first time and actually looking for a solution to the same problem which is asked here.

Here is my TinyMCE Script:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#elm1",
    images_upload_credentials: false,
    theme: "modern",
    branding: false,
    <!-- elementpath: false, -->
     menubar:false,
     <!-- preview_styles: false, -->

    height:300,
         automatic_uploads: false,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ]

});
```

> Now, How To Remove Right Click Image Url Option?

Just Remove the **image** From **plugins**

```
plugins: [
        "advlist autolink link lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ]
```

Comment: Is this same process for removing table?

Answer (score 0):

For people using TinyMCE 5, a solution may be to explicitly specify the items allowed in the [context menu](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/contextmenu/#contextmenu):

```
tinymce.init({
  ...
  contextmenu: 'link table' /*just do not mention the 'image'*/
  ...
});
```